# Sort command in bash script does not work when called from Jenkins

Tags: bash, sorting, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I am trying to execute a shell script on a windows node using Jenkins.

The bash script uses `sort -u` flag in one of the steps to filter out unique elements from an existing array

```
list_unique=($(echo "${list[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '))
```

Note - shebang used in the script is `#!/bin/bash`

On calling the script from command prompt as - `bash test.sh $arg1`

I got the following error -

> -uThe system cannot find the file specified.

I understand the issue was that with the above call, sort.exe was being used from command prompt and not the Unix sort command. To get around this I changed the path variable in Windows System variables and moved `\cygwin\bin` ahead of `\Windows\System32`

This fixed the issue and the above call gave me the expected results.

However, When the same script is called on this node using Jenkins, I get the same error again

> -uThe system cannot find the file specified.

**Jenkins stage calling the script**

```
stage("Run Test") {
  options {
    timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES')
  }
  steps {
    script {
      if(fileExists("${Test_dir}")){
        dir("${Test_dir}"){
          if(fileExists("test.sh")){
            def command = 'bash test.sh ${env.arg1}'
            env.output = sh(returnStdout: true , script : "${command}").trim()
            if (env.output == "Invalid"){
              def err_msg = "Error Found."
              sh "echo -n '" + err_msg + " ' > ${ERR_MSG_FILE}"
              error(err_msg)
            }
            sh "echo Running tests for ${env.output}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Kindly Help

Comment: And the same `PATH` fix cannot be applied in that script, or in the calling Jenkins job?

Comment: As an aside, the first `tr` can be avoided; `printf '%s\n' "${list[@]}" | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: Since i made system PATH variable change on the node where jenkins is running the job. I assumed i would not have to make any changes the jenkins job. Even if jenkins uses a different user since the system PATH variable has been modified it should use the correct sort command. Help me understand if I am wrong here.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Jenkins on Windows but what I do know is that environment variables (too) are a mess on Windows. As a workaround, overriding the `PATH` in the script itself should be well-defined and deterministic.

Comment: Cygwin on Jenkins is sometimes a bit tricky to set up. For debugging, I always invoked a small Cygwin program as the first step in a Jenkins job, which essentially dumped the environment. In your case, the first I would do is to explicitly write `/usr/bin/sort -u` in your pipe. If it works then, we know that the problem was with the PATH. Also, I suggest to start your Cygwin bash scripts on Jenkins by explicitly writing `bash --login SCRIPT`, and put the cygwin specific initializations (including PATH reordering) into `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`.